# How do I connect a return value from a callback function to a dynamically generated button in Streamlit?

Tags: python, streamlit

I am generating a bunch of Streamlit buttons in a loop for movie titles from a google sheet. The callback function is the same for each button. The callback function has a return value. When the button is clicked it calls the function.

I want to read the return value from the function into a variable and use it to display the movie poster.

```
rh_movie_list = data[user].to_list()
for title in rh_movie_list:
    if type(title) is float:
        break
    with col1:
        st.button(
            title, key=title, on_click=get_movie_art, args=(title,),
            use_container_width=True
        )

def get_movie_art(poster):
    poster_path = f'{movie_art_endpoint}{poster}'
    return poster_path
```

How do I attach the click to a dynamically generated button? Is there a way to do it within the same loop that creates the button?

Comment: I think you need to display the movie poster in the callback.

Comment: What are your trying to achieve, something like a poster viewer where if the user presses the button A it will show poster A, and if user presses button B it will show poster B?

Comment: @ferdy - yes, I'm trying to display a poster when the title button is clicked. But the titles are always changing in the google sheet.

Comment: @mkrieger1 - I was afraid of that.It's a problem to display the poster in the callback, because I have multiple users with some movie titles overlapping from user to user, and each user has a different Streamlit page.

Comment: Instead of returning a value from callback function, you can create a session variable to store the poster_path of the clicked button title., then render that poster_path which is now in session variable.